# Python eval() builtin function

Tags: python, interpreter, built-in, bnf

After looking for some reference online I still do not understand how eval() really works, maybe I am missing a key component, hopefully someone can guide me to the right docs or explanation.

Suppose:

```
def foo(x,y):
    print(x)
    print(y)
```

Use eval() to call foo().

Example 1:

```
eval('foo(1,2)')
```

Example 2:

```
eval('foo')(1,2)
```

According to python 3.6 documentation, the way I am calling eval() on example is how it should be done, as I am passing everything as a string, However, for example #2 I still do not understand why python interpreter also evaluates correctly.To me when running eval() on the second example the python interpreter should return a TypeError requiring 2 missing arguments. I am hoping if someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: `foo` is a valid Python expressions. Functions are just another type of object. Try it in the interpreter

Answer (score 4):

This is a valid Python expression:  `foo`.  It evaluates to the function.  You can then call it.  This is why `foo(1, 2)` works.  You can also do this:

```
x = foo
x(1, 2)
```

So `eval("foo")` evaluates to the function foo, which you can then call.